# s3slider not Displaying

Tags: html, slider

I have been at this for hours, and I still can't understand why it won't work.

I followed the demonstration at http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/, the only change I made was to replace "s3slider" to "slider" (I've done the same with the css file).

I have included jquery and s3slider.js libs in my header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="js/s3Slider.js"></script>
```

My slider is just like any other basic layout:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul id="sliderContent">
        <li class="sliderImage">
            <img src="img/portfolio-1.jpg">
            <span>Your text comes here</span>
        </li>
        <li class="sliderImage">
            <img src="img/portfolio-2.jpg">
            <span>Your text comes here</span>
        </li>
        <div class="clear sliderImage"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I also included the function call before the closing body tag>:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').s3Slider({
        timeOut: 4000       //in milliseconds
    });
});
</script>
```

Nothing is wrong with the CSS, I am pretty sure about that.

Any Help would much be appreciated.

Comment: can you send me the demo

Comment: or just make a demo on jsfiddle.net for everybody

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net is free

Comment: Never Mind, I solved the issue. Thanks though @RachelGallen

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna change the main id you have to replace the s3slider with your new id in all palce like s3sliderContent, s3sliderImage

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#slider').s3Slider({
        timeOut: 4000
    });
});
```

```css
#slider {
    width: 400px; /* important to be same as image width */
    height: 300px; /* important to be same as image height */
    position: relative; /* important */
    overflow: hidden; /* important */
}
 
#sliderContent {
    width: 400px; /* important to be same as image width or wider */
    position: absolute; /* important */
    top: 0; /* important */
    margin-left: 0; /* important */
}
 
.sliderImage {
    float: left; /* important */
    position: relative; /* important */
    display: none; /* important */
}
 
.sliderImage span {
    position: absolute; /* important */
    left: 0;
    font: 10px/15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    width: 374px;
    background-color: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* here you can set the opacity of box with text */
    -moz-opacity: 0.7; /* here you can set the opacity of box with text */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.7; /* here you can set the opacity of box with text */
    opacity: 0.7; /* here you can set the opacity of box with text */
    color: #fff;
    display: none; /* important */
    top: 0; /*
        if you put top: 0;  -> the box with text will be shown 
                                at the top of the image
        if you put bottom: 0;  -> the box with text will be shown 
                                at the bottom of the image
    */
}
 
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
    <ul id="sliderContent">
        <li class="sliderImage">
            <img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/26383513/superthumb.jpg">
            <span>Your text comes here</span>
        </li>
        <li class="sliderImage">
            <img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/26383513/superthumb.jpg">
            <span>Your text comes here</span>
        </li>
        <div class="clear sliderImage"></div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the working demo.
[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/g9fc6x21/)